# Get the users identity from a DLL the website loads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DLL that is dynamically loaded from a web app. Inside this DLL I need to get the users identity. I cannot pass this from the web app to the DLL as I do not control the web app part.

I know in the web app I could get this ID with:

```
Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

But not sure how I can get this from inside my DLL as this doesn't seem available inside my DLL. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you do `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` or `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`?

Comment: That worked thank you!

Comment: Mark jwatts' answer as accepted then.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [User property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.100).aspx) on the [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext_properties(v=vs.100).aspx) object. You will need to reference [System.Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web(v=vs.100).aspx) in your library.